# How to select the code prompted by nvim ,and jump to the prompted document

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim, rust-analyzer

I'am using the `coc-rust-anaylzer` plugin
Now the problem is I can only see the a prompt, but **I don't know how to select the options he gives me**, I have tried enter, which only breaks the line and doesn't select it,I have also tried the tab key, and it doesn't work, it won't select the option but only switch the option. And when **I want to check the document for an particular option in detail**, I don't know how to switch to that document box to look at it more closely,is there a way or material to help solve this problem directly or indirectly
[image]

Comment: Have you even checked the coc.nvim readme? The readme is pretty comprehensive in how to configure coc.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand it very well. I don't even know much about vim itself, and I've been looking for a good way to learn how to configure vim, just like the people on GitHub who know how to craft the vim to IDE-like.I think it is really cool

Comment: Learning vim is a gradual process: do not expect to master it in a few days. Have you tried vim tutor? Also check [vim-galore](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore) and [Learn  vim script the hard way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).

Comment: I have finished the vim tutor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map your `<cr>` to select the completion item:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

Comment: I've been seeing things like <expr><silent> for a long time that are more advanced for me. I want to learn vim further systematically, but the official documentation of vim is really too longto read, and there is no need to learn so much.Is there any material for learning vim at the right length and depth?

Comment: This is really a helpful answer. Thanks fannheyward.  I'm able to select the suggestions using the ENTER key.

Comment: @Cyberlin Just paste this into your ~/.config/init.vim the reload neovim (just restart it). Then when you get a dropdown suggestion hit enter. I don't understand any of this either hahahaahahaha